# Inject Mocking using TypeMock

Tags: typemock, typemock-isolator

I using Ioc pattern(Ninject) in my application. I want make a test case (using TypeMock) to testing Ioc pattern(Ninject). but I don't know how to mock object which creating using Ninject. Kindly let me know how can I inject mock or inject dependencies using TypeMock. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're testing but you might be interested in using [Isolate.Swap](http://blog.typemock.com/2010/07/typemock-back-to-basics-faking.html)

Just create a fake object and then call Swap so that the next instance created shall be a fake one - no need for Ioc:

```
var fakeObject = Isolate.Fake.Instace<MyObject>();
Isolate.Swap.NextInstace<MyObject>().With(fakeObject);
// Call code under test
```

The first object of type MyObject created after this code will be a fake object.

If you do want to use Ioc to inject your fake object you need to be able to set it to return the object created using *Isolate.Fake.Instace*.